# Get IList item by concrete type using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have the following:

```
public IList<ISignupStepViewModel> Steps { get; set; }
```

An example of a concrete implementations of ISignupStepViewModel would be:

```
public class SignupStepBillingViewModel : ISignupStepViewModel
 public class SignupStepPricingViewModel : ISignupStepViewModel
```

I initialize `Steps` with concrete classes that implement `ISignupStepViewModel` with the following:

```
Steps = typeof (ISignupStepViewModel)
            .Assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && typeof (ISignupStepViewModel).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .Select(t => (ISignupStepViewModel) Activator.CreateInstance(t))
            .ToList();
```

I would like to now get a specific item in `IList<ISignupStepViewModel> Steps` with Linq, something like:

```
var billingStep = (SignupStepBillingViewModel)signupObj.Steps.FirstOrDefault(t => typeof(t) == SignupStepBillingViewModel);
```

Is there a way to do this? Currently I am getting the error "Class name is not valid at this point" on SignupStepBillingViewModel in bold:

(SignupStepBillingViewModel)signupObj.Steps.FirstOrDefault(t => typeof(t) == **SignupStepBillingViewModel**);

Comment: Would you want to include *subtypes* of `SignupStepBillingViewModel` as well? If so, `OfType` is your friend.

Comment: `OfType` is generic, so in this case I think it won't be usable.

Comment: @Brian MajoB answer will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the keyword: *is*
instead of: *typeof(t) == SignupStepBillingViewModel*

```
var billingSteps = signupObj.Steps.Where(t => t is SignupStepBillingViewModel).Select(t => (SignupStepBillingViewModel)t).ToList();
```

Comment: `is` is better that the comparison it replaces but you could use `OfType` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
signupObj.Steps.FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetType() == typeof(SignupStepPricingViewModel)) as SignupStepPricingViewModel;
```

Comment: Just use `OfType` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx, if that was not available you could use the `is` operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help, the simplest solution, that @JonSkeet suggested in the comments was:

```
 var billingStep = Steps.OfType<SignupStepBillingViewModel>().First();
```

Comment: This is the right answer, credit to @JonSkeet for telling you in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
Steps.Select(t => typeof(t) == SignupStepBillingViewModel);
```

will produce a collection of `bool`values which you then try to case to your object. Try this:

```
var billingStep = (SignupStepBillingViewModel)Steps.FirstOrDefault(t => typeof(t) == SignupStepBillingViewModel);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you suggestion, that was a mistake on my part to use Select instead of FirstOrDefault. I have updated my answer because your answer is not working

Comment: Just use `OfType` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx, if that was not available you could use the `is` operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx.

Comment: Additionally, your code doesn't compile -1, you'd have to do `t.GetType() == typeof(Signup...)` but don't, see my previous comment.